# How to make my own base Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to my own basic `MainWindow`. I'd than create a new `MyWindow` which inherits all the controls and stuff from custom `MainWindow`.

I tried to google it but I haven't found answer to my problem. When I try to use a new `Window` as base for another `Window` Visual Studio says:

> WpfApplication1.MainWindowCustom cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base `Window`s can only be created using code, not XAML.

So basically this is what you have to do:

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
    // custom logic here
    // add controls, etc.
}
```

Then you derive from that `BaseWindow` in every other `Window`:

```
<local:BaseWindow x:Class="SomeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace.To.Local"
>
</local:BaseWindow>
```

And:

```
public partial class SomeWindow : BaseWindow
{
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. What you're saying is that i have to create every control from the code, not xaml?

Comment: Indeed. Visual Studio doesn't support base classes created using XAML.